# How do I SELECT records out a table based on TIME?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with contents that I need to show depending on what the time is.

My table "flightSched" has two columns, first one representing "Flight Numbers", and the other "Arrival Times" these contents as shown below:

```
flightNo    arrivalTime
WEE2013     13:00:00    
SKE2013     14:00:00
KEY2013     18:00:00
```

I am trying to display records based on the arrival times. 
Below are my time variables:

```
//Time 30 minutes ago
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = date('H:i', strtotime('-0 minutes'));        
//Time in 4 hours
$CurrentTimePlus4Hours = date('H:i', strtotime('+240 minutes'));

$query  = "SELECT * FROM flightSched WHERE 
                 FROM_UNIXTIME(arrivalTime) BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME('$CurrentTimeMinus30min') AND 
                 FROM_UNIXTIME('$CurrentTimePlus4Hours')
                 ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC ;";
```

When I run the query NOTHING is printed out at all. Even when the flight arrival time is within the specified time in the query.  Can anyone explain why this happens, and perhaps also show me how to correctly write the query to print out records based on the times given?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: After executing query add line `echo mysql_error();` to see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

The MySQL function `FROM_UNIXTIME` expects a timestamp, whereas you provide an already-formatted time.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM flightSched 
WHERE arrivalTime BETWEEN '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours'
ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC
```

I assume that your `arrivalTime` column is of MySQL-type `TIME`.

Comment: Yes my arrivalTime column is MySQL type TIME. I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work. Are you sure that the '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' and '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours' variable types are compatible with the TIME type in the query?

Comment: @SirBT: as the PHP variables are only added to the query string, it should work. MySQL should be able to handle the strings as `TIME` literals. I created a dummy table `test` and the following works in my case: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE arrivalTime BETWEEN '12:00' AND '15:00'`. The result yields all entries with `arrivalTimes` between the two provided times. Additionally, PHP yields this time format for what you do: `echo date('H:i', strtotime('+240 minutes'));` echoes (in my case): `00:39`.

Comment: I tried out the query in phpMyAdmin and it yields the expected results, however when I try it out in MySQL with the varialbes '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours', I dont get any results.